# Simple Spring application not deploying in WAS Liberty 8.5.5.4

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty

I am using WAS Liberty profile 8.5.5.4 trying to deploy simple spring hello world application which worked in WAS 8.5, using spring-4.0.6 tried with both jdk-7 and jdk-6 but get the following exception below and the server shuts down

> 0000001f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl
>   I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created:
>   "java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   com.ibm.ws.anno.classsource.internal.ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer
>   196" at ffdc_15.01.18_00.25.40.0.log  0000001f
>   ws.anno.classsource.internal.ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer W
>   CWWKC0004W: [
>   ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer@1446811651(WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar,
>   com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@786d5926)
>   ]: The conversion of [MimeMessageHelper.class] as
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedEntryImpl@159bca2b]
>   under root
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@62f6de35]
>   for prefix [org/springframework/mail/javamail] failed.  0000001f
>   ws.anno.classsource.internal.ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer W
>   CWWKC0004W: [
>   ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer@1446811651(WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar,
>   com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@786d5926)
>   ]: The conversion of [JavaMailSenderImpl.class] as
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedEntryImpl@60b6c966]
>   under root
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@62f6de35]
>   for prefix [org/springframework/mail/javamail] failed.  0000001f
>   ws.anno.classsource.internal.ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer W
>   CWWKC0004W: [
>   ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer@1446811651(WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar,
>   com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@786d5926)
>   ]: The conversion of [InternetAddressEditor.class] as
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedEntryImpl@aadafa7]
>   under root
>   [com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedContainerImpl@62f6de35]
>   for prefix [org/springframework/mail/javamail] failed.  00000001
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A
>   CWWKE0036I: The server MySpringServer stopped after 1 minutes, 31.484
>   seconds.

and see the following in ffdc logs

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   com.ibm.ws.anno.classsource.internal.ClassSourceImpl_MappedContainer
>   196

## Server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false"/>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>


<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
<logging traceSpecification="*=audit:*=debug" traceFormat="ADVANCED" consoleLogLevel="ERROR"/>

<enterpriseApplication id="ZimpleWebApp" location="ZimpleWebApp.ear" name="ZimpleWebApp"/>
```

Any ideas on whats causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across same issue. It was some issue when upgrading from WAS Liberty 8.5.5.3 to 8.5.5.4 resulting in the issue. I just did a clean 8.5.5.4 install and tried, it works now.